# Warum gibt es keinen "Trompetisten"?

Tags: etymology, suffix

Ja, ich weiß - es heißt *Trompeter*. Aber für nahezu alle gängigen (mit Planstelle in einem normalen Sinfonieorchester vertretenen) Instrumente gibt es für die Musiker, die sie spielen, Bezeichnungen, die auf *-ist* enden: *Fagottist, Cellist, Posaunist*... Manchmal existiert noch eine zweite Bezeichnung wie *Geiger*, manchmal ist diese sogar üblicher (jedenfalls kannte ich bis vor kurzem nur *Bratscher*, aber nicht [*Bratschist* und *Violist*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bratschist)).

Nur für *Trompeter* (und evtl. *Schlagzeuger*, wenn man diese nicht als *Perkussionisten* bezeichnen will) fehlt eine solche Variante. Ist das Zufall, weil Sprache eben nicht ganz logisch ist, oder hat es einen tieferen Grund?

Comment: Ich hab mal nach Trompetist gesucht. Es gibt hier und da ein paar Annoncen, die das verwenden, aber viel ist es nicht. In anderen Sprachen (Dänisch, Schwedishc) scheint es aber Standard zu sein. Insofern schon interessant warum bei uns nicht.

Comment: Eine Theorie wäre, dass der Term eben nicht im Orchester sondern bei der Armee geprägt wurde, die es nicht so "fancy" brauchte. Die meisten anderen Instrumente hat man vor allem im Orchester. Aber ich habe null Belege dafür.

Comment: @Emanuel Laut dem verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel spielt der Violist Viola (also Bratsche), und nicht etwa Violine.

Comment: Violist spielt Viola (Bratsche), Violinist spielt Violine (Geige).

Comment: @Emanuel Die Theorie, daß es mit der militärischen Herkunft des
Wortes zusammenhängt, klingt zumindest plausibel. Die anderen
klassischen Militärmusiker, der Trommler und der Pfeifer,
haben auch *-er* statt *-ist*.

Comment: *Trompetist* scheint nicht ganz ungebräuchlich zu sein: z.B. [link](http://www.musiker-in-deiner-stadt.de/kleinanzeigen.finden/trompetist-trompeter-gesucht-muenchen); übrigens auch im Niederländischen heisst er "trompettist".

Answer (score 10):

*Trompeter* ist von *trompeten* abgeleitet, nicht von *Trompete*. Die von Uwe im Kommentar genannten *Trommler* und *Pfeifer* haben ihre Herkunft auch in den Verben. Das gilt weiterhin auch für den *Geiger*, der sich vom Verb *geigen* ableitet.
Die Kette ist wie folgt:

> Trompete -> trompeten -> Trompeter
>   Trommel -> trommeln -> Trommler
>   Pfeife -> pfeifen -> Pfeifer
>   Geige -> geigen -> Geiger

Die Endung *[-er](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/er.html?country=D)* ist die gängigste Endung bei der [Verb-zu-Nomen-Suffigierung](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/V-To-N/Suffig.html#Anchor-ohne-14210) (Vergleiche: rauchen -> Raucher / laufen -> Läufer).

Zusätzlich sind das alles germanische Wörter. Die Endung *-er* ist wohlbemerkt ein heimisches Suffix.

Für die folgenden nicht-germanischen Wörter (weitestgehend aus dem Italienischen übernommen) gibt es keine Verben und die Musiker sind direkt vom Musikinstrument abgeleitet.
Hierbei wird das Fremdsuffix *[-ist](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe-F/ist.html?country=D)* für die [Nomen-zu-Nomen-Suffigierung](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/N-To-N/Suffig.html?MenuId=WordFormation11110#Anchor-Fremdsuffixe-21683) verwendet. Fremdsuffixe werden – wie der Name andeutet – in aller Regel auf Wörter fremdsprachlicher Herkunft angewendet.

- (Kontra)Bass -> (Kontra)Bassist
- Fagott -> Fagottist
- Cello -> Cellist
- Violine -> Violinist
- Viola -> Violist
- Gitarre -> Gitarrist
- Mandoline -> Mandolist
- …

Interessant ist eine Ausnahme: Der *Bratschist* wird auch als *Bratscher* bezeichnet, und das obwohl es weder das Verb *bratschen* gibt, noch die *Bratsche* germanischen Ursprungs ist.

Eine kleine Ausnahme ist auch noch der *Schlagzeuger*. Das Verb *schlagzeugen* gibt es nicht. Das Wort ist direkt vom *Schlagzeug* abgeleitet. Hier greift also nur die Theorie der germanischen Wortherkunft.

---

Alle Wortbildungen kann man auf canoo.net nachzuschlagen. Als Beispielreferenz hier der [Trompeter](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/trompeter:N:M) und der [Fagottist](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/fagottist:N:M).

Comment: +1, auch wenn noch einige Fragezeichen bleiben: Es gibt das Verb _flöten_, trotzdem spricht man nur vom _Flötisten_ (früher _Flötenisten_). _Harfe_ ist ein altes _deutsches_ Wort, das schon früh (15./16. Jh., wenn ich die Quelle bei [Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=harfenist) richtig lese) das Suffix _-ist_ bekam. Und den inzwischen gelöschten Einwand von @Takkat, dass zumindest die [Grimms](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=trompeter) nicht sicher waren, ob _Trompeter_ von _Trompete_ oder _trompeten_ stammt, möchte ich stehen lassen.

Comment: Und dann wäre auch noch zu (er)klären, warum man heute nur noch vom _Posaunisten_ spricht, obwohl man früher auch [_Posauner_](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=posauner) verwendet hat und das Verb [_posaunen_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/posaunen) existiert und alle zusammen einen deutschen Stamm haben - und warum _Trompeter_ keine vergleichbare Entwicklung gemacht hat.

Comment: @Matthias Gute Einwände. "Posaunist" scheint genau so eine Ausnahme zu sein wie Bratscher, nur halt genau andersrum. "Flötist" kommt aus dem französischen und ist von "Flöte" abgeleitet. Laut DWDS war es früher "Flötenist" und noch weiter zurück "Flöter". Bzgl. "Harfe" ist die Herkunft laut DWDS weitesgehend ungeklärt, aber "Harfenist" ist vom Nomen abgeleitet. – Soweit scheinen Bratscher, Posaunist, Flötist und Harfenist die Ausnahmen zu bilden und man müsste diese untersuchen. Trompeter ist dagegen voll im Muster.

Comment: @Em1 Soweit d'accord, nur was_Harfe_ angeht, sehe ich bei DWDS nur Unklarheiten hinsichtlich der "Ursuppe", aber eine klare Aussage zu einer bis ins Althochdeutsche reichenden Wurzel. Was etwas kurios ist, denn _Harfenist_ scheint bislang sogar die älteste all dieser Musikerbezeichnungen zu sein, obwohl, wie Du ja selbst schreibst, die Suffixierung eher mit Fremdwörtern passiert.

Comment: @Matthias Sorry, hatte den Link nicht verfolgt, daher klang es zunächst für mich nach dem Schema nach *Harfist*. Besonders gut finde ich übrigens den Grimmschen Zusatz "der nit darzu singt" :-D

Comment: @Matthias Das hatte ich schon verstanden ;-) Trotzdem finde ich, es klingt lustig. Interessant auch, dass Grimm sehr wohl den *Harfer* führt und auch das Verb *harfen* als *Harfe spielen*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar DWDS listet auch "harfen"

Answer (score -3):

Warum sollte da ein tieferer Grund vorliegen? Es gibt eben Wörter, wo das Wortbildungselement -er nicht so gut passt. Bass + er hat nicht gefallen. Und Saxophon+er auch nicht.

Comment: Wenn wir unser ganzes Leben lang schon "Saxophoner" sagen würden, hätte deine Antwort gelautet, dass "Saxophonist" einfach nicht gut klingt.

Comment: @Em1, hätte, wenn un aber zählt leider nicht; genausowenig dass kein tieferer Grund vorliegt. Irgendeinen phonetischer und/oder prachhistorischen Grund könnte man sich sicher zusammenreimen. So müsste, falls vom Plural abzuleiten, eigentlich vom Bässer gesprochen werden, oder ob ein Verb "bassen" zugrunde liegen müsste, das ebenfalls fehlt (außer auf einem komischen Antifa-Aufkleber). Ob das besser wäre sei dahingestellt, oder ob \*basseur zu sehr nach *baiseur* "Ficker(in)" ('tschuldige bitte) klingen würde.